# jquery load() is hiding an unrelated background image in another DOM element

Tags: jquery

I have a div on my site ("button_form") that has a jquery .on("click") function assigned to it, such that when clicked another div ("popup_box") appears in the middle of the screen when clicked.  I am using load() to populate the content of popup_box from another html source.  The problem is that when the load() function is executed, it hides a completely unrelated background image on the site ("banner")

I've tried removing the one line of the jquery (marked below as PROBLEM LINE!) and the "popup" div works perfectly, and the background image is not hidden... so I know it's load() that is the problem.

How can I dynamically load content into my popup_box and not affect my banner background image?

Note: the whole thing works as planned on my local machine, but when I upload it to the web, it no longer works - that is, the banner background image disappears when the button_form is clicked.  Nothing has changed, the code is exactly identical, and I'm using the exact same browser.

Thanks for your help!

index.html

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

    <div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup_box"></div>

    <div id="banner"></div>

    ....

    <div id="button_form"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

bannerSwap.js

```
// art
var art = new Array();
art[0] = "_img/banner_database.jpg";
art[1] = "_img/banner_cloud.jpg";
art[2] = "_img/banner_trends2.jpg";
art[3] = "_img/banner_team.jpg";

var img = 1;              // starting slides
var qty = 4;              // total number of slides


function newBanner(){ //this function is executed every 4 seconds

    document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage="url('" + art[img-1] + "')";

    // set the next image in the queue    
    if(img<qty){
        img++;
    }else{
        img=1;
    }
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button_form').on("click", function(){

        $("#overlay").show(0);

        $("#overlay").fadeTo(500,0.5);

        $("#popup_box").show(0);

        $("#popup_box").animate({
            height:'700px',
            width: '500px',
            margin:'125px 0 0 -250px'}, 
            500,   // duration:
            // *****  PROBLEM LINE: ******
            function(){$(this).load('_includes/form.html')} 
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any new css files included by the `_includes/form.html` page? One problem could it is overriding the existing styles. Check the content loaded by the load and inspect the styles applied to banner using the browsers developer tools

Comment: wow. you're right!  i was loading a css file in the form.html which was already loaded into index.html... i removed it, and now it works! THANK YOU!

Comment: how do i give you credit for this?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned it in the comment, it could be problem with css overriding.

Please check the contents loaded by `_includes/form.html` to see whether any css rules(style sheets) are loaded and inspect the styles applied to the banner to see whether any new rules are applied to it